# Is it possible to create complex images (like cross functional flowchart) with Graphviz?

Tags: python, graphviz

I need to create a complex image with lanes (like a cross functional flowchart). Is it possible to use Graphviz to automatically (based on a csv file) generate something like the picture below? If not, how can I achieve that?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could probably render some of it in Graphviz, such as in the [cluster example](https://www.graphviz.org/_pages/Gallery/directed/cluster.html), but Graphviz isn't really suited to this type of diagram. Its strength is directed graphs and hierarchical info.

Have a look at some of the declarative graphics libraries such as [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/) or [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) or [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/). There is various levels of support for plotting axes in the style of lanes, then the rest is mostly textual annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, Graphviz could probably do it, but the spline connecting the 12 triangular nodes would be the only "easy" part of the effort.  For everything else, you would explicitly position/draw the nodes, swimlanes, and arrow edges.  Ugh!
The dpic variant of the pic language is closer fit, but I don't think it supports rotated text

I'd look at TikZ, Asymptote, and/or straight SVG

I don't know what your input file looks like, but the mapping to your output language will be challenging.  Good luck.